# Use if condition in radiobutton

Tags: android, android-activity, radio-button

I am developing android project. In this, in one activity, I set 2 radio buttons.
I want that to if I select(Check) the 1st radiobutton, it will go to activity2.if I select(Check) the 2nd radiobutton, it will go to activity3. I don't want any buttons.What is the event I have to use. Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

this will help you...

in xml

```
<RadioGroup
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        android:background="#FF0"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Radio_Windows_Phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Windows Phone 7 Silverlight Cookbook"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Radio_IOS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Swift Development with Cocoa"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            />
```

in java

```
    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View v)
    {
        //require to import the RadioButton class
        RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Radio_one);
        RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Radio_two);

        //is the current radio button now checked?
        boolean  checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();

        //now check which radio button is selected
        //android switch statement
        switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.Radio_one:
                if(checked)
                    //if first selected
                break;

            case R.id.Radio_two:
                if(checked)
                    //if second selected

                break; 
        }
```